# "Add file" option with uploaded music playlist view

Tags: html, playlist

Hello i want to make music player with html, css and javascript. I know how to do almost everything i want to add to this player but i have problem with one feature. I want to add playlist view with "Add file to playlist" option to add your own music to playlist. I am looking for another day how to do it but there is no information anywhere. In every tutorial video music files are prepared in folder and their locations are embedded in the code. This is not what a music player should look like, because the user wants to listen to their music that they want to add to the playlist. Could you explain me how to create playlist and "Add file to playlist" option? I really care about making this music player. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a **Java script** like this :

- Add a button within your songs **To add to a playlist** and add `onclick` event
- So whenever that button is clicked a function is executed
- That function at first asks the name of playlist
- if that name is already there in your directory of user then ask him to save in that only and add that music link to that
- otherwise let user enter the name and make a playlist with that name and add that song to it
- As adding music one by one can hamper user experience so let user select more than one song
- Also whenever user clicks a playlist add an option to **edit** & play . So that user can delete any music if he/she want.